# How to copy an image's name using php

Tags: php, image-uploading, delete-file

have an upload script where I can delete an image I have to write manually its name in an input box in a form.I read the images' names directly from a folder in my server. I'd like to copy the name of the image that I want to delete by clicking on the image or on its name for each image that I want to delete. It's not easy to explain it, I will show you the code:

**EDIT2:** It'working:

```
    <?php




if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'GET' ) {
    if (isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name'] != '') {

        $img_file = $_GET['name'];

    if($img_file){
        unlink("img/$img_file");
    header('Location: index.php');
}
}
}

?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['upload_img'])){

$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];      
$file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$file_tmp_name  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if($file_name){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name,"img/$file_name");

            }
}
?>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label>upload image </label><br>
<input type="file" name="image"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="upload_img">

</form>


<?php

$folder = "img/";

if(is_dir($folder)){

        if($handle = opendir($folder)){

            while(($file=readdir($handle)) != false){

            if($file==='.' || $file==='..') continue;

echo '<a href="index.php?name='.$file.'">';
echo '<img src="img/'.$file.'" width="150" height="150" alt="">';
echo '</a>';

 }
 closedir($handle);
} 

}
echo '<br>'.$file_names;
?>


</body>
```

Comment: What errors you are getting ?

Comment: I don't get errors. To delete an image I have to write manually the name in the input box. I'd like to copy the name automatically clicking on an image or on its name for each image that I want to delete

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? You'll need to add a click handler to your image elements. And if you want the text clickable, you'll probably want to wrap that in a `span` or something.

Comment: I edited my post, please see it. Thanks

Comment: Based on the answers below, you should clarify the desired behavior.  Do you want images to be deleted as soon as a user clicks on them?

Comment: yes, I want to delete the image by clicking on the image or on its name :)

Comment: You should probably reword your question then.  As it stands write now, the question appears to focus more around the act of populating an input box with text when an image is clicked. If the real goal is simply to trigger a deletion of the image on click, you should make that more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your img tag in an anchor tag like so

Assuming your current script is called `mypics.php` you could do this.

```
echo '<a href="mypics.php?name="' . $file . '">';
echo '<img src="img/'.$file.'" width="150" height="150" alt="">';
echo '</a>';
```

Now at the top of your current script you add

```
<?php
// picture clicks will be returned as GET requests
if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'GET' ) {
    if (isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name'] != '') {

        // do any sanity checks that you are only 
        // deleting a sensible file name etc

        // delete the file
}


// your existing script follows, which should re-paint the page
// without the deleted image
```

You can now delete the code you were using for entering the name and processing the delete that way

Comment: While this gets to the ultimate goal, it doesn't really answer the question the OP asked.  Perhaps OP doesn't want images instantly deleted on click and wants the user to actually have to submit the form.

Comment: @PatrickQ Perhaps what the OP really wanted was someone to write a complete piece of code for them so they dont have to bother. I would do it utilizing AJAX, but I am definitely not going to sit and write a complete and properly tested image management system for them. ___Nor should anyone be expected to here___

Comment: I completely agree.  I'm just noting (mostly for OP's sake) that your answer (while good) doesn't explicitly do what they asked so that OP could better craft the question around what is actually wanted.

Comment: @PatrickQ Actually you made me think about the solution again and I came up with what I believe is a better suggestion now anyway.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried your solution but it's not working, can you check the second edit in my first post please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `img` tag inside `a` tag, with a link to a script that deletes the file, something like:

```
echo <<< EOF
<a href="deleteFile.php?fileToDelete=$file"> <img src="img/$file" width="150" height="150" alt=""> </a>
EOF;
```

Then create a file called, `deleteFile.php`

```
if(isset($_GET['fileToDelete')){
//NOTE: Make SURE you filter and restrict the content of $_GET['fileToDelete'), or may get all the files removed...
//remove the file here
}
```

Comment: While this gets to the ultimate goal, it doesn't really answer the question the OP asked. Perhaps OP doesn't want images instantly deleted on click and wants the user to actually have to submit the form.

Comment: It's not clear at this point, but I guess he can use it after. Thank you for pointing that anyway.